Confused with the product of Feynman propagators
While reading Thomas Rauh's 'Introduction to Feynman integrals and multiloop techniques' I came across the following identity $$\frac{1}{A^aB^b}=K\int^1_0 \frac{dx x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{[xA+(1-x)B]^{a+b}}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are Feynman Propagators, and $K$ was a constant term consisting of ratio of gamma functions.
Following was an example given in the text $$\begin{align}F(a,b)&=c\int \frac{dl}{[l^2]^a[(l+q)^2-m^2]^b}\\&=c'\int_0^1 dx x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\int \frac{dl}{[l^2+2(1-x)l\cdot q +(1-x)q^2-xm^2]^{a+b}}.\end{align}$$
When I calculated it myself, the coefficient for the $m^2$ term came out to be '-(1-x)' instead of '-x'.
